# Can only start bottle server from command line?

Tags: python, bottle

Have a bottle simple bottle server that starts fine if we use command line

```
a@abc:~/work/scripts>python BServer.py
Bottle v0.12.18 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

But when that is executed from another process that restart system everyday, bottle server seems to fail and keep failing on

```
run(host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, port=8088)
```

I suspect it can a missing import or not correct permission on the import but still havent manages to pin point the exact root cause.
Any ideias what can be causing it ? or how i can dump bottle log to a file ?

Thank you.

Comment: Added  some comments on the python script that starts the bottle server, juso confirm paths..


 paths
['', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/a/work/scripts']  run
23-Feb-2021 (07:52:28.819426) start server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on pypath /home/a/work/scripts
 call run

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Some suggestions so that we can help you: (1) Move your comment into your question (you can "edit" your question). (2) Show us your code--just the parts that matter, please. (3) Show us how it's failing--the error messages and stack trace.

Comment: are you killing the process correctly before trying to respawn it?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps.
Found python was failing on subsequent runs, because they were started by another user ).
Script had this line :

```
import os
os.environ['HOME']
```

Home was not define resulting in crash.